# R - Meta-Analysis - How to create a forest plot with robust estimates from clubSandwich functions

Tags: r, metafor

I have a quick question about displaying robust estimates in a forest plot.

I am using `rma.mv()` from the `metafor` package to fit a multilevel random-effects model. For robust estimates, I use the `conf_int()` and `coef_test()` functions from the `clubSandwich` package. However, the `forest()` function from `metafor` only accepts objects of class `rma`, which are not produced by the functions for robust estimates.

Is there any way to use the `forest()` function to create a nice forest plot, but somehow integrate the robust overall estimate from the `clubSandwich` functions?

Appreciate any advice or alternative solutions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `forest()` to plot the individual estimates and then `addpoly()` to add the polygon. For the latter, you just need to pull out the pooled estimate and corresponding standard error from the object returned by `coef_test()`.